# Finding the general solution of a PDE by changing variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Currently working through some university homework and I can't seem to see where I've went wrong with the question.

Screenshot of question:

[image]

As you can see I have used the correct partial derivatives at the beginning and subbed them into the original PDE, however I am clearly missing something and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculus is correct : 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2y\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}-\frac{x}{y^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
\end{cases}$$
$$y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} +x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}+ 2yx\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2} \right)\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
$$
Then from the original PDE you can see that 
$$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2} \right)\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
=8\left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2} \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=8$$
Integration with respect to $v$ leads to :
$$z=8v+F(u)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$z=8(x^2-y^2)+F\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$